# Telerik MVC Grid for 40 tables with WCF limitations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, telerik

I need some suggestions on how to resolve the issue I am having. I have tried several different options but hit limitation after limitation. Here is a brief overview of what is going on...

We have 40 tables that hold configuration data that needed to implement CRUD operations. We must use Telerik MVC Grid and preferably the INLINE editing. We must manage the original state and the changed properties on a single object. That object will later be serialized into the database for later approval.

Instead of making 40 models, 40 views, 120 crud methods(no delete), that will all closely share the same code except the field names. I am trying to create a way to make this generic enough where we can have 40 models (maybe?), 1 view, 3 crud methods.

I am running into limitation in various areas:

- WCF doesn't support generics
- Telerik grid doesn't support dynamic types
- WCF doesn't keep methods and private properties intact
- We are using MEF also, so this is a plugin, inside of a plugin.. i know..
- Adding methods to the WCF layer is not permitted...

My Idea?
I thought I would try creating a class to hold the state, well call it ManagedState. I originally wanted the table models to inherit from it and I had it linked to track changes but this was not working.

I also have now tried using the ManagedState class separately from the configuration class
and using that strictly to pass back and forth through our WCF service. Then try using that data to create the original type and hydrate it.

Really there is so much that has gone into this I am flustered. I have no particular code to share as this is an overall question of how I would implement it as I am hitting brick walls all over. I can post code in future if I get a good response to attempt another method to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question had a lot of views so I figured I would respond to answer my question.

I pretty much used T4 templates to generate a TelerikGrid HTMLHelper. The Telerik grid code was generated for each type unfortunately but all I had to do was call the helper and pass my type in and it used a case statement to return the correct grid.